# Ошибка 'dict' object has no attribute 'chat'

Tags: python, telebot

Столкнулся с ошибкой

> chat_id = message.chat.id AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'chat'.

Помогите, пожалуйста!
Когда доходит до `def tinkoffusdt(message)`, бот выдает ошибку:

```
chat_id = message.chat.id
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'chat'
```

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    button = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    button.add(types.KeyboardButton('ТИНЬКОФФ - USDT'), types.KeyboardButton('СБЕРБАНК - USDT'))

    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                           'Привет это обенник Паркер. \nВыбирай способ оплта и забирай крипту по вкусному курсу.\n'
                           'Выбирай нужную пару', reply_markup=button)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, choice)


def choice(message):
    if message.text == 'ТИНЬКОФФ - USDT':
        tinkoffusdt(message)
    elif message.text == 'ТИНЬКОФФ - USDT':
        pass
    else:
        main(message)


def tinkoffusdt(message):
    button = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    msg = price = cg.get_price(ids='bitcoin,litecoin,ethereum,tether', vs_currencies='rub')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'USDT = {price["tether"]["rub"] * 1.07} Рублей\nМинимальная сумма обмена'
                                      f'составляет 500 рублей.\n Введите суммму вашего депозита', reply_markup=button)

    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, proverka)

def proverka(message):
    try:
        global course
        course = {}
        proverka = {}
        proverka["tinkoffusdt"] = message.text
        course = float(proverka["tinkoffusdt"])

        if course >= 5000:
            bot.send_message = (message.chat.id, 'Одобрено')
        else:
            bot.send_message = (message.chat.id, 'Минимально 5000')
            tinkoffusdt(message)
    except ValueError:
        bot.send_message = (message.chat.id, 'Введите корректную сумму')
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anna K\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\lolo\ChiefKeef.py", line 54, in <module>
    bot.polling()
  File "C:\Users\Anna K\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1043, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "C:\Users\Anna K\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1118, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\Anna K\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1074, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\Anna K\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 148, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\Anna K\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 91, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Anna K\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\lolo\ChiefKeef.py", line 21, in choice
    tinkoffusdt(message)
  File "C:\Users\Anna K\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\lolo\ChiefKeef.py", line 34, in tinkoffusdt
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, proverka)
  File "C:\Users\Anna K\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 4968, in register_next_step_handler
    chat_id = message.chat.id
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'chat'
```

Comment: Приведите полный стэктрэйс ошибки

Comment: Да, нужен полный трейс, а сейчас непонятно, где именно ошибка выходит. Видимо, в библиотеке бота, потому что такой строки в приведённом коде нет.

Comment: chat_id = message.chat.id
        self.register_next_step_handler_by_chat_id(chat_id, callback, *args, **kwargs) Я начинающий в этом деле, не судите строго. Это же стрэкрейс?

Comment: Нет, полный текст ошибки начинается со слова Traceback

Comment: Вот тут я подозреваю `msg = price = cg.get_price(ids='bitcoin,litecoin,ethereum,tether', vs_currencies='rub')` что в msg словарь записывается, и дальше вы msg передаете в proverka, а она вызывает tinkoffusdt. А должно передаваться message, которое в саму функцию tinkoffusdt пришло.